# TCL : Regarding source , package , namespace command

Tags: tcl

I want to know about modular programming in tcl and how we can achieve that .

In some tcl tutorials mention like source command having some drawbacks in achieving "modularity" so that we came to the "package" after that "package" is having some more drawbacks so that we came with the combination of package and namespaces .

I want to know what are the drawbacks and proper hierarchy of 3 concepts .  Can Anyone help me ?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if I understand your question correctly, so I'll try to explain the 3 commands you throwed in your question:

- [`source`](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/source.htm): Evaluates a file as a Tcl script. - 
  It simply opens the file, reads until the EOF character (`^Z` on both windows and *nix) and evaluates it.
  It does not keep track of sourced files, so you can source the same file again (great for hotpatching), but this is the drawback: It will source the file again.
- [`package`](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/package.htm): Manages packages. It basically keeps track of the provided packages and tries to figure out which file it has to source to load a new package.
- [`namespace`](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/namespace.htm): They provide context for commands and variables, so you don't have to worry about unique names for your commands. Just the namespace has to be unique. Has nothing to do with loading packages or other modules, it just provides namespaces.

I suggest that you use packages, each package in it's own file, each package with a namespace equal to the package name where all commands reside.
You should export the public commands with `namespace export`.

Comment: Packages can be — and often are — implemented by a mix of Tcl and C code; `package` looks after all that complexity for you. It also handles versioning and all that sort of stuff.

Comment: @Johannes: In your statement regarding source command , You said like the same file will be sourced again and it is the drawback . In packages also if we modify any file it has to be soured . So we will call that using "package require" command , the package require command internally sourcing the same file right ? Where we are getting the difference between package and source ?

Comment: if you do a second `package require` the file will not be sourced again, because `package` knows that the package is already there.

Comment: Then how the changes in a perticular file will be reflected ? and we have the statement can be automatically executed with the package ifneeded statement which is having the source command . The File should source again in my point of view . Is it not the case ?

Comment: do you know about iTCL?

Comment: @Dru : Yeah I know that iTCL is Object Oriented . Any link to this question there ?